# How to create a keyboard shortcut for Preview `Move To…`

Tags: macos, preview, keybindings

Using App shortcuts in System Preferences -> Keywords allows me to create a shortcut but it does not work when I try it in Preview.

I tried the following keybindings (which do not conflict with preview's bindings):

⌥⌘M, ^⌥⌘M,  ⌥⌘K, ^⌥⌘K

Comment: Move to ? Trash ? what are you trying to accomplish? you can not assign shortcuts for commands that do not exist in Preview. You can use Automator or schript and create a action, then assign a keyboard shortcut to that.

Comment: @Buscar웃 The command "Move To…" **does** indeed exist in Preview...

Comment: @klanomath I only have the "Move to Trash", but that is on Mavericks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't apply it to "Preview" but to "All Applications" in "System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts" any unused shortcut will work:

[image]

and the resulting Preview menu:

[image]